# Photoshop: how to reduce banner quality without changing its size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, file-size

Google only accepts banners under 150kb. When I reduce my 160kb banner by 5% using the "Save for Web" tab, the size changes to 149kb but the banner size changes as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Don't change size percentage. Lower the quality instead.

[image]